# How to retrieve service definition in controller when service was defined in yaml config?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I'm playing with [Symfony2 DependencyInjection](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/components/dependency_injection/definitions.html#getting-and-setting-service-definitions). I defined service in yaml and want to `$container->getDefinition($serviceId)` in controller but got InvalidArgumentException. Is it possible to retrieve service definition in controller when service was defined in **yaml** config?

```
//services.yml   
 services:
        patriots:
            class: CwBundle\Utils\PatriotsClass
            calls:
                 - [setBrady, ['%brady%']]

        broncos:
            class: CwBundle\Utils\BroncosClass
            arguments: [@patriots]



//controller
        $container = new ContainerBuilder() ;
        $a = $container->hasDefinition('patriots');
        $b = $container->findDefinition('broncos');
        $c = $container->getMethodCalls('patriots');
       //print_r $a,$b,$c
```

> The service definition "broncos" does not exist.

I have a feeling that this entire [symfony.com/doc/components/dependency_injection](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/components/dependency_injection/index.html) section is for those who define services in PHP, not yaml.

---

edit:
the reason of the confusion is that Chapter:"Working with Container Service Definitions" is before Chapter "Compiling the Container" in Symfony DI Documentation.

Comment: From your link: "The methods here that change service definitions can only be used before the container is compiled. " Symfony 2 compiles your container and stores it in the results.  You won't be able to do anything with definitions from a controller.  Take a look at compiler passes: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html and see if they meet your requirements.  But you won't be able to mess with existing service definitions based on a route.

Comment: @Cerad Thank You for answer. I have no requirements, I'm just reading this dep-injection--documentation and "play" with methods showed there with my services defined in yaml configuration. (But this "playing" means throwing exceptions). So if service is defined in yaml you cant manipulate it anymore?

Comment: The documentation link is for dependency injection in general for Symfony2, including all available formats (yml, php, xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can manipulate your service no matter you use yaml, php or xml.

In your exemple you create a fresh new ContainerBuilder so it's empty and obviously you can't retreive a service from this new instance.

From your controller you'll have the container, it's already compiled and you can't alter services.

You can only alter services before container is build. It's in your Extension file inside DependencyInjection folder or when using CompilerPass. at this time you will have access to ContainerBuilder.

Comment: the reason for this confusion is that Chapter:"Working with Container Service Definitions" is before Chapter "Compiling the Container".

Answer (score 0):

To get a service in controller you call

```
$this->container->get('name_of_service')
```

Comment: By "retrieve service definition" I don't mean just service but sevice definition like here http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/components/dependency_injection/definitions.html#getting-and-setting-service-definitions (There is no explanation what `$container` is)

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you don't need to instantiate your own container but you need to use the application container.

So try this:

```
    $container = $this->container;
```

instead of this;

```
    $container = new ContainerBuilder() ;
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thank You for answer. With $this->container I have no access to methods from ContainerBuilder object that I pointed in a main post. But I guess it's for a reason. @metfan post already cleared my mind.